# Error using fzero for f=(x.^3).*cos(x) in a loop

Tags: matlab, function, for-loop, function-parameter

I try to find all the roots of the function `f=(x^3)*cos(x)` between -6pi and 6pi using `fzero`.

I create a function:

```
function y3=f(x)
  f=(x^3)*cos(x);
end

% Then at the command window:

syms x;
fun=@f
x1=-6*pi;
x2=-5*pi;
r=zeros(1,12);
for i=1:12
  x=fzero(@fun,[x1 x2]);
  r(i)=x;
  x1=x1+pi;
  x2=x2+pi;
end
```

I got this error:

```
Error: "fun" was previously used as a variable, conflicting with its use here as the name of a function
or command. See "How MATLAB Recognizes Command Syntax" in the MATLAB documentation for details.
```

How can I solve it? Thank you

Comment: Your function body should be `y3=(x^3)*cos(x);` instead of `f=(x^3)*cos(x);`

Comment: You write `fun=@f`, and later `@fun`. In this second statement, you are treating `fun` as a function, but it's declared as a variable by your first statement. The solution is to write `fzero(fun,...)` or `fzero(@f,...)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have an answer for you. According to the [fzero](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fzero.html#inputarg_fun) documentation on the `fun` input to `fzero`, you can directly input an anonymous function. Hence you can do something like this:

```
clc; clear;

x1=-6*pi;
x2=-5*pi;

r=zeros(1,12);

for i=1:12
    x=fzero(@(x) (x.^3)*cos(x),[x1 x2]);

    r(i)=x;

    x1=x1+pi;    
    x2=x2+pi;    
end
r
```

This gave an output of:

```
r =

-17.2788  -14.1372  -10.9956   -7.8540   -4.7124         0         0    4.7124    7.8540   10.9956   14.1372   17.2788
```